# Android location fix inaccurate/old but Google Maps works

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

This is a strange issue which mostly appears on Samsung devices but I cannot confirm its only on Samsung.

My app won't get or update to the correct location fix. It listens to GPS, network and cell providers but the location fix I get is still outdated and inaccurate sometimes the fix is like a day earlier.

I thought it might be a bug in my code but then I opened other apps (Yelp, etc...) and they also have the same  problem.

I then open Google Maps and the location is perfectly accurate and up-to-date.

Is this an Android platform bug? Do Maps use a different internal location source provider? Has anyone dealt with this issue before and can provide a solution?

Comment: I've seen this too, and only with Samsung devices.  The app listens to location updates and doesn't get any.  Many third party apps fall back on a cached location, but none of them can get a new fix.  Sometimes they get fixes with bad times (even saw a few with a 0 timestamp).  Google Maps appears fine; my suspicion is that they also use WiFi data directly for triangulation, but that's only a guess at this point.  Rebooting is usually required to get the location services working again.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with a htc and a sony device, if you ever find an answer let please give an answer here. have been monitoring this for a while now and nobody seems to know the answer

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.
It is an Android platform bug and it seems that this is an open issue that Google knows about:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57707

It is randomly happening.
Google maps is working because their location is based on Google services (Fused Location) which you can also use. 
But they also have a bug with the january 2014 update: if you are outside and request a fastest location update rate (e.g. every second) and you are connected to the both network and gps receiver, you will receive a new location only at around 10 seconds even if gps is connected.
They ruined my app which used to work fine with this update and still not fixed to this day!

So what you can do is wait for the fix or use google location service fused location if it fits for you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings>wifi>advanced and turn off ALWAYS ALLOW SCANNING

Comment: How does this answer the question?