# (android) why my location is little bit not accurate and some times far from my real location

Tags: android, google-maps

why my location is little bit not accurate and some times far from my real location, my real location in **red sign** and some times my location detect in **green sign** it's so far from my location

how do i can fix that?

[image]

this my code for detect my location

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;

        this.googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

        GoogleMapOptions option = new GoogleMapOptions();
        option.compassEnabled(true);
        this.googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);

    }

    private OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            if(awal) {
                awal=false;
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes

```
In android accurate location is  68% confidence.
```

if you draw a circle centered at this location's latitude and longitude, and with a radius equal to the accuracy, then there is a 68% probability that the true location is inside the circle.

In statistical terms, it is assumed that location errors are random with a normal distribution, so the 68% confidence circle represents one standard deviation. Note that in practice, location errors do not always follow such a simple distribution.

This accuracy estimation is only concerned with horizontal accuracy, and does not indicate the accuracy of bearing, velocity or altitude if those are included in this Location.

If this location does not have an accuracy, then 0.0 is returned. All locations generated by the LocationManager include an accuracy

more details Refer [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29)

Comment: if using packet data the accuracy is like my picture above, but if using wifi my location almost 100% accurate

Comment: when we use mobile data Cell towers cover a several mile area so they aren't the best for getting a location.so thats based on your mobile network coverage i think

Comment: how about google maps? google maps still accurate when use mobile data

Comment: Google maps is working because their location is based on Google services (Fused Location)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867363/android-location-fix-inaccurate-old-but-google-maps-works

Comment: how i can fix that? there's no answer/example